# ant install to deploy Tomcat webapp failing with permission problem

Tags: tomcat, ant

I've been following along the very good Tomcat6 [Application Developers Guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/index.html). I've grabbed their `build.xml` which contains the handy ant task called `install` that uses the `catalina-ant.jar` task `deploy`.

```
<target name="install" depends="compile"
   description="Install application to servlet container">

    <deploy url="${manager.url}"
       username="${manager.username}"
       password="${manager.password}"
           path="${app.path}"
       localWar="file://${build.home}"/>

</target>
```

My project sits currently in `/home/leif/test/mytomcatapp/`.

My `build.properties` looks like:

```
manager.username=admin
manager.password=admin
manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/
cataline.home=/usr/share/tomcat6/
```

And my `/etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml` looks like:

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager" />
```

But, when I do my `ant install` to test out my webapp I get an error deploying it:

```
$ ant install
Buildfile: build.xml
Trying to override old definition of datatype resources

prepare:

compile:

install:
   [deploy] FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /mytomcatapp

BUILD FAILED
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /mytomcatapp
```

And in `/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out` it says:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/leif/test/mytomcatapp/build (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copyInternal(ManagerServlet.java:1644)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copy(ManagerServlet.java:1605)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:350)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

So Tomcat manager can't access the files in my home dir. Nothing shocking there. But how is the `ant install` task ever expected to work? This is of course presuming people keep the source code for their project in their home dir and excute `ant install` from that location. I'd rather not crank open the permissions on my home dir, there must be a better way?

Comment: I've since switched from Ant to Maven for building my webapps. I include `catalina` as a dependency and get a `mvn tomcat:deploy` command and others for free. It's far simpler and just-works. http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/org.apache.tomcat/catalina/6.0.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need package up your webapp in a .war file, and have ant upload it to Tomcat. If you're using the sample [build.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/build.xml) , just have the install target depend on the `dist` target, and change

```
localWar="file://${build.home}"
```

to

```
war="${dist.home}/${app.name}-${app.version}.war"`
```

Alternativly, change your build.xml to output the war to a directory that you can share with tomcat - e.g. somewhere under /tmp

Comment: Thanks, this gave me the idea to define `build.home=/tmp/public/build/` in my `build.properties`. The Tomcat manager can no happily grab my files to deploy.