# Tomcat ant tasks execution error

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, tomcat7

I have problem with running tomcat ant tasks.
I found couple of similar cases, but not one helped:

[ant install to deploy Tomcat webapp failing with permission problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579626/ant-install-to-deploy-tomcat-webapp-failing-with-permission-problem)

[Why is Ant returning a 403 on deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116467/why-is-ant-returning-a-403-on-deploy)

[Ant Tomcat 7 Reload FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163438/ant-tomcat-7-reload-filenotfoundexception)

Versions:

- **OS:** Windows 7 x64 Professional
- **Java version:**   1.6.0_25
- **Ant version:**    1.8.3
- **Tomcat version:** 7.0.011

**My tomcat-users.xml:**

```
    <tomcat-users><role rolename="manager-script"/>
       <user username="script" password="script" roles="manager-script"/>       
       <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
       <user username="manager" password="manager!" roles="manager-gui"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

**Part of Ant script:**

```
<property name="app.name" value="london"/>
<property name="manager.url" value="http://localhost:8081/manager/text"/>
<property name="manager.user" value="script"/>
<property name="manager.password" value="script"/>
<property name="update.filename" value="update.war"/>   

<taskdef name="tomcatStart" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask"/>
<taskdef name="tomcatStop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask"/>
<taskdef name="tomcatDeploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"/>          

<target name="main">
<tstamp/>
<tomcatStop
    url="${manager.url}"
    username="${manager.user}"
    password="${manager.password}"
    path="/${app.name}"                    
/>

<tomcatDeploy
    url="${manager.url}"
    username="${manager.user}"
    password="${manager.password}"
    path="/${app.name}"
    war="file:${update.filename}"                                          
/>
</target>
```

**Console output (StopTask):**

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\username\ant\build.xml:34: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
http://localhost:8081/manager/text/stop?path=%2Flondon
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1434)

at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask.execute(StopTask.java:73)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

**Console output (DeployTask):**

```
  BUILD FAILED
  C:\Users\username\ant\build.xml:35: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 f
  or URL: http://localhost:8081/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Flondon
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)

  at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:228)
  at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:211)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

  Total time: 0 seconds
```

Strange thing is that I got it worked couple of times, but now it doesn't work again.

Another strange thing is that 
StartTask and StopTask generate FileNotFoundException but 
DeployTask generates java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403...

Is it possible that error caused by encoded (%2F) slash symbol in path?

Thanks a lot)

Comment: this may be a silly question, but are you sure that http://localhost:8081/manager/text points to the manager servlet? Isn't it just http://localhost:8081/manager ?

Comment: Yes, for Ant tasks url must be "/manager/text". "/manager/" is used for GUI access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all settings are OK:

- I deleted Tomcat folder
- unpacked new copy
- applied settings

and everything works now.

My bad not to check it that way earlier.